# In Unity how do I stop perpetual math statements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, static

The question is simple but I can't for the life of me, figure it out.

My logic goes like this

```
// Static floats are StatBase.maxHealth = 0 and rStat.maxHealth = 70

class rStat : Monobehaviour
{

    
    public bool nomatter = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            nomatter = true;
        }


        if (nomatter == true)
        {
            healthcalc();
        }

        void healthcalc()
        {
         StatBase.maxHealth += rstat.maxHealth; // StatBase.maxHealth should = 70 but the 
                                                // number never stops adding

         nomatter = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `heathcalc` should be outside `Update`.

Comment: @Kiner_shah That worked immediately and I am SO grateful. Thank you for taking the time to answer such a silly question. I'm still in the crawl phase of learning and the little bits of information that get by like this are infuriating to pinpoint.

Comment: how is "number never stops adding" ?? this code looks worked on every single click.

Comment: if you click a lot of times , maxHealth value will be 70+70+70+70 , so is it your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest that logic is quite strange.

Why have this `bool` flag if you already **have** one you want to act on? You can simply do

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        healthcalc();
    }
}

// in general rather put this on class level and don't nest it under Update
void healthcalc()
{
     StatBase.maxHealth += rstat.maxHealth; 
}
```

or if there is only one line anyway even

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        StatBase.maxHealth += rstat.maxHealth;
    }
}
```

Comment: the mouse click is not part of the actual logic. in game the player will click a button like "accept" to allocate a stat point which will then increase that stats amount. My problem is that it was in the update method so it didn't matter what I was doing it would always just be actively adding. Thanks for the answer though I appreciate the help.